# Django group and sum QuerySet for template

Tags: django, django-views

Hoping someone can help! Apologies if the question isn't well written, this is my first post.

I am trying to pass a queryset through to a template - I get an error if I do not pass the timesheet pk through (pk in example output below) but I do not want to do that as it interferes with a group by:

```
    pk  staff_number week_number week_start  hours contractor_id
    1   12345        31          2020-10-24  15    1
    2   12345        30          2020-10-17  7.5   1
    4   12345        30          2020-10-17  10.0  1
```

Basically, I want the output to grouped to display only TWO rows (2020-10-17 should be one row with 17.5 hours in total).

My model is:

```
   from django.db import models
   from django.contrib.auth.models import User


    class Contractor(models.Model):
        user = models.OneToOneField(User, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        staff_number = models.CharField(max_length=9, null=True)
        contractor_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
        date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)

        objects = models.Manager()

        def __str__(self):
            return f"{self.staff_number}: {self.contractor_name}"


    class WeekList(models.Model):
        week_number = models.SmallIntegerField(null=True)
        week_start = models.DateField(null=True)

        objects = models.Manager()

        def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.week_number}: ({self.week_start})"


    class Timesheet(models.Model):
        user = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
        contractor = models.ForeignKey(to='timesheet.Contractor', null=True, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
        week_list = models.ForeignKey(to='timesheet.WeekList', null=True, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
        job_number = models.CharField(max_length=16, null=True)
        sat_hours = models.FloatField(default=0, null=True, blank=True)
        sun_hours = models.FloatField(default=0, null=True, blank=True)
        mon_hours = models.FloatField(default=0, null=True, blank=True)
        tue_hours = models.FloatField(default=0, null=True, blank=True)
        wed_hours = models.FloatField(default=0, null=True, blank=True)
        thu_hours = models.FloatField(default=0, null=True, blank=True)
        fri_hours = models.FloatField(default=0, null=True, blank=True)
        timesheet_revision = models.SmallIntegerField(null=True)
        date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)

        objects = models.Manager()

        def __str__(self):
            return f"{self.contractor} {self.week_list.week_start} {self.timesheet_revision}"
```

This is snippet of the views.py that I am struggling with:

```
query = Timesheet.objects.filter(user=user_id).values('pk','contractor__staff_number', 'week_list__week_number', 'week_list__week_start').query

query.group_by = ['contractor__staff_number', 'week_list__week_number', 'week_list__week_start']

timesheets = QuerySet(query=query)

total_timesheets = timesheets.count()

print(total_timesheets)

for timesheet in timesheets:
    print(f"{timesheet.pk} {timesheet.contractor.staff_number} {timesheet.week_list.week_start} {timesheet.contractor.pk}")

total_timesheets = timesheets.count()

print(total_timesheets)
```

Could anyone give some advice how to group the data by Week Start and sum by hours (I have had the sum working with an annotate but have taken it out until I get the grouping right)?

Also, could anyone tell me why the first print(total_timesheets) displays 2 but the 2nd one displays 3??

```
2  << 1st total_timesheets
1 12345 2020-10-24 1
2 12345 2020-10-17 1
4 12345 2020-10-17 1
3  << 2nd total_timesheets!
```

Hope you can save my sanity!

Update: I've got the QuerySet that returns the grouped data by using this (sure it's not the 'best practice' way but it works):

```
query = Contractor.objects.filter(user=user_id).values('pk', 'staff_number', 'timesheet__week_list__week_number').annotate(
    count_timesheets=Count('timesheet__week_list', distinct=True)).query
```

I can get the data out of the QuerySet this way:

```
for contractor in contractors:
    print({'id': contractor.id, 'name': contractor.contractor_name, 'week_start': contractor.timesheet_set.values('week_list__week_start'), 'count': contractor.count_timesheets})
```

How can I refer to the week_start field in a template (the reference method above doesn't work, of course)?

Answer (score 0):

```
Timesheet.objects.filter(user=user_id).values('week_list ').annotate(hour=Sum('hours'))
```

try this query

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Didn't work though. 

Unless I put the pk in the `values` list , I keep getting a `'NoneType' object has no attribute 'attname'` error in the webpage and `TypeError: 'Timesheet' object is not subscriptable` and `KeyError: 'week_list'` errors in the command window.

Comment: if u put the pk u will get the all rows cuz pk is unique